# allure command line from python

Tags: python, allure

Is there a way to call allureCLI from Python? I would like to use python instead than shell scripting to run multiple reports.

I could use Popen but I am having so many issues with it, that I would rather avoid it unless there is no other way around

Answer (score 1):

Since the Allure CLI script calls a java application makes it a Python to Java problem. There are a few solutions like Py4J that can help you with that. Keep in mind that most solutions rely on the Java app already running inside the secondary application before being called from Python.

Comment: Good point; I didn't realize that the app is in fact a java binary, so it is impossible to run it natively from Python. I wish there was a native solution for python; so I can also avoid to install JRE on the machine running the parsing of the results file.
I guess I have not many options: either popen() or write a shell script that call allureCLI. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that the conversion from XML to JSON can be achieved in other ways as well as the format is quite predictable. That said, it would probably come down to re-implementing the Java code into Python.

Comment: Yep, it is a matter to build the XML files and parse the JSON to get the exact same results, but if I have to re-write all that shebang, I am better off just using their java binary and be done with it...until someone will actually find time to make a python module.